# Rails 3.2.2 log files unordered, requests intertwined

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, logging

I recollect getting log files that were nicely ordered, so that you could follow one request, then the next, and so on.

Now, the log files are, as my 4 year old says "all scroggled up", meaning that they are no longer separate, distinct chunks of text. Loggings from two requests get intertwined/mixed up.

For instance:

```
Started GET /foobar
...
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 0.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
Patient Load (wait, that's from another request that has nothing to do with foobar!)
[ blank space ]
Something else
```

This is maddening, because I can't tell what's happening within one single request.

This is running on Passenger.

Comment: I think is related http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4483390

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep!, they have made some changes in the `ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger` so it is not any more waiting until the request has ended to flush the logs:

- http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4483390
- https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/04ef93dae6d9cec616973c1110a33894ad4ba6ed

But they have added the [ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TaggedLogging.html) which is very funny and you can *stamp* every log with any kind of mark you want.

In your case could be good to *stamp* the logs with the *request UUID* like this:

```
# config/application.rb
config.log_tags = [:uuid]
```

Then even if the logs are *messed up* you still can follow which of them correspond to the request you are following up.

You can make more funny things with this feature to help you in your logs study:

- [How to log user_name in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811393/how-to-log-user-name-in-rails)
- http://zogovic.com/post/21138929607/running-time-in-rails-logs

Answer (score 4):

I tried to search for the same answer but couldn't find any good info. I'm not sure if you should fix server or rails code.

If you want more info about the issue here is the commit that removed old way of logging https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/04ef93dae6d9cec616973c1110a33894ad4ba6ed

Answer (score 4):

If you value production log readability over everything else you can use the

```
PassengerMaxInstancesPerApp 1
```

configuration. It might cause some scaling issues. Alternatively you could stuff something like this in application.rb:

```
process_log_filename = Rails.root + "log/#{Rails.env}-#{Process.pid}.log"
log_file = File.open(process_log_filename, 'a')
Rails.logger = ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger.new(log_file)
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, if you happened to get a PID of a previous process, that would overwrite your older log file.  This could be mitigated to some degree by frequent rotation, but since PID's are not something you can count on, that still is not 100% safe.  I think you'd want to add a timestamp or something to the log file name.  Also: the PassengerMaxInstancesPerApp suggestion is pretty useless, bordering on snarky; I'd remove it from your answer.

Comment: I downvoted this answer, because you should never have suggested that PassengerMaxInstancesPerApp change. It's akin to suggesting a line of code that deletes your root directory if someone asks how to free up hard disk space. Please revise.

Comment: The PassengerMaxInstancesPerApp is partly a joke, but also a real solution if you're using it during development.

Answer (score 3):

Well, for me the TaggedLogging solution is a no go, I can live with some logs getting lost if the server crashes badly, but I want my logs to be perfectly ordered. So, following advice from [the issue comments](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5388#issuecomment-6174010) I'm applying this to my app:

```
# lib/sequential_logs.rb
module ActiveSupport
  class BufferedLogger
    def flush
      @log_dest.flush
    end
    def respond_to?(method, include_private = false)
      super
    end
  end
end

# config/initializers/sequential_logs.rb
require 'sequential_logs.rb'

Rails.logger.instance_variable_get(:@logger).instance_variable_get(:@log_dest).sync = false
```

As far as I can say this hasn't affected my app, it is still running and now my logs make sense again.

Answer (score 0):

They should add some quasi-random reqid and write it in every line regarding one single request. This way you won't get confused.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it, but I believe [Lumberjack's `unit_of_work` method](https://github.com/bdurand/lumberjack#units-of-work) may be what you're looking for. You call:

```
Lumberjack.unit_of_work do
  yield
end
```

And all logging done either in that block or in the yielded block are tagged with a unique ID.